# mysql where clause based on another query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get a single query to work rather than two where the first makes an array and then loop through the other.

The first query returns a set of users, and then I want to query another table based on these users, with a bit of research I ended up with this but it doesn't work...

```
SELECT FreeText, (
    SELECT EmailAddress FROM customers WHERE AccessLevel = 'callcentre'
) AS User FROM orders WHERE FreeText = User
```

I would prefer to do a single query but if thats not possible then I will work around it with the first creating and array then looping through the second

Any help appreciated

Example results, User would contain names, e.g. lsmith, nrowe, pmerle

Then the second query would retrurn the order rows where they are set as the FreeTxt

Example table structure

```
customers table
Id, Email,  Add1,        Add2    ect...
23, lsmith, someaddress, road...

Orders
Id, customerId, FreeTxt, Product
54, 23,         lsmith,  mob
```

Output for this would be lsmith + Id from orders I only asked for FreeTxt whilst testing

Comment: Can you post table structure with sample data and expected output.

Comment: For security reasons I can't reveal too much more than I have

Comment: You need to reveal something more or we can only guess what the solution is. It probably involves a `JOIN` but on what we can't say. Rename columns to something more generic if you must. That's usually better anyway, it makes the question more broadly applicable.

Comment: Sir you can show dummy table..

Comment: Then mask the data, or provide pesudo-data/sampledata. You need to be able to provide *something*.

Comment: That should help

Comment: The table structure is useful but your sample output is still not very clear

Comment: what is `pmerle` from the example?

Comment: a name of someone in the table

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to show what the user have ordered ? @LewisSmith

Comment: Not really but that would provide the correct output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The subquery  is not necessary you can do the same  with a inner join
but be sure that the  orders.FreeText  = customers.EmailAddress really match

```
  SELECT orders.FreeText, customers.EmailAddress
  FROM orders
  INNER JOIN customer on orders.FreeText  = customers.EmailAddress 
        and customers.AccessLevel = 'callcentre';
```